# go install - do I need to manually update my path?

Tags: macos, go

I'm a bit confused on what the latest best practice is with Go.

Installing the latest (1.17) Go on macos, with no GOPATH env variable, with go mod, I see the following is in my path

`/usr/local/go/bin`

When I run `go install <something>`, then that ends up in `~/go/bin/<something>`. So why is `~/go/bin` not in my path? Do I have to add it manually?

Comment: "why is ~/go/bin not in my path"  There's on obvious way to automatically put it in your path, which is usually configured by the shell's config like @aureliar says

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you have to manually add `~/go/bin` to your `PATH`.

To do so, add this line in your shell init file (`.bashrc`, `.zshrc` ...):

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin
```

Comment: Is this still considered common practice?

Comment: Yes. This is still where executable installed via `go install` are located