# Setting GO path in environment variables ~/go/bin

Tags: go, wails

I have installed Go and if i check Go version it returns me
`go version go1.20.3 darwin/amd64`

Now i want to setup wails

I first enter

```
go install github.com/wailsapp/wails/v2/cmd/wails@latest
```

but when i enter

`wails doctor will check if you have the correct dependencies installed. If not, it will advise on what is missing and help on how to rectify any problems.`

i am getting command not found

I have also set Path by entering

`echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/Users/devn/go/bin' >> ~/.bashrc`

but still i am getting error wails not found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [go install - do I need to manually update my path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70098792/go-install-do-i-need-to-manually-update-my-path)

Comment: Executables are installed in the directory named by the GOBIN environment variable, which defaults to $GOPATH/bin or $HOME/go/bin if the GOPATH environment variable is not set. Executables in $GOROOT are installed in $GOROOT/bin or $GOTOOLDIR instead of $GOBIN. See https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Wails executable is not being recognized by your system.

You can try the commands below:

1. `echo $PATH`

   Check if `/Users/devn/go/bin` is included in the output.
2. `source ~/.bashrc`

   After modifying the PATH variable, reload the shell configuration for the changes to take effect. Restart the terminal or run the above command to reload the configuration.
3. `ls -l /Users/devn/go/bin`

   Now verify that the 'wails' executable is present in the directory by running the above command.
4. If none of the above steps resolve the issue, try reinstalling wails by running:

   `go get github.com/wailsapp/wails/v2/cmd/wails@latest`

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:-
wails doctor
zsh: command not found: wails
mkdir ~/go
mkdir: /Users/devn/go: File exists
export GOPATH=~/go
go install github.com/wailsapp/wails/v2/cmd/wails@latest

export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin

sudo ~/.bashrc

sudo: /Users/devn/.bashrc: command not found

sudo ~/.bash_profile

sudo: /Users/devn/.bash_profile: command not found

source ~/.bashrc

wails version
v2.4.1